# Как сохранить файл на сервер, который автоматически скачивается при посещении страницы?

Tags: php

Собственно весь вопрос в заголовке.
Использовал **file_put_contents**, но как и ожидалось, он сохранил php-страницу, вместо файла, который скачивается при ее посещении.

Вот пример такой страницы https://w8shipping.com//getPhotosArchive.php?id=728759

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы просто не умеете использовать `file_put_contents` и видимо не читаете мануалы.

```php
file_put_contents("photos.zip", fopen("https://w8shipping.com//getPhotosArchive.php?id=728759", 'r'));
```

Из мануалов

```php
 file_put_contents(
    string $filename,
    mixed $data,
    int $flags = 0,
    resource $context = ?
): int
```

> Если data является потоковым ресурсом (stream), оставшийся буфер этого потока будет скопирован в указанный файл. Это похоже на использование функции stream_copy_to_stream().

Comment: Шик! Спасибо большое! Плохо прочитал доку)

Answer (score 0):

За мгновенное скачивание отвечает HTTP заголовок Content-Disposition

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Для PHP что-бы передать ZIP указываем так:

```php
<?php
$filename = "zip_filename.zip";
header("Content-Type: application/x-zip; charset=ASCII");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"zip_filename.zip\"");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
exit;
```

Ещё советую глянуть документацию на заголовок Content-Range - который отвечает за докачку файла с сервера. Скажем если твой скрипт поддерживает докачку, то можно не бояться за обрыв связи и пользователь на медленном модеме не будет страдать скачиванием файла с нуля если вдруг оборвалась связь.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Range